# Table with daily historical stock prices. How to pull stocks where the price reached a certain number for the first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with historical stocks prices for hundreds of stocks. I need to extract only those stocks that reached **$10 or greater** for the first time.

| Stock | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 9 | 2021-10-01 |
| AAA | 10 | 2021-10-02 |
| AAA | 8 | 2021-10-03 |
| AAA | 10 | 2021-10-04 |
| BBB | 9 | 2021-10-01 |
| BBB | 11 | 2021-10-02 |
| BBB | 12 | 2021-10-03 |

Is there a way to count how many times each stock hit >= 10 in order to pull only those where count = 1 (in this case it would be stock BBB considering it never reached 10 in the past)?

Since I couldn't figure how to create count I've tried the below manipulations with min/max dates but this looks like a bit awkward approach. Any idea of a simpler solution?

```
with query1 as (
    select Stock, min(date) as min_greater10_dt
    from t 
    where Price >= 10
    group by Stock
), query2 as (
    select Stock, max(date) as max_greater10_dt
    from t 
    where Price >= 10
    group by Stock
)    
select Stock
from t a
join query1 b on b.Stock = a.Stock 
join query2 c on c.Stock = a.Stock
where not(a.Price < 10 and a.Date between b.min_greater10_dt and c.max_greater10_dt)
```

Comment: If you add your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: And actually add your desired results, because now that I have answered I'm not clear exactly what you are expecting to see.

Comment: "in this case it would be stock BBB considering it never reached 10 in the past" - that doesn't really make sense, BBB hit greater than 10 twice in the data provided, so did AAA, just AAA had a value lower than 10 in-between.

Comment: There is also a syntax error in your query - good to ensure any code you post is working first.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a first grader in front of a strict teacher lol.  I guess it's easy to assume that not everybody here who asks questions is an experienced developer and a frequent user of stackoverflow. I'm not a developer at all, I don't work in IT I just occasionally use SQL to pull the data, so I have no idea what is DDL+DML (actually now I do since I googled it). And yes, syntax errors are expected, that's one of the reasons people come here - to learn how to correct their errors. Thank you for the solution though, it worked.

Comment: The more effort you put into writing a good question, the better chance you get the answer you want - hence why we encourage people to write good quality questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem which can be solved as follows:

- detect the change from < 10 to >= 10 using a lagged price
- count the number of such changes
- filter in only stock where this has happened exactly once
- and take the first row since you only want the stock (you could group by here but a row number allows you to select the entire row should you wish to).

```
declare @Table table (Stock varchar(3), Price money, [Date] date);

insert into @Table (Stock, Price, [Date])
values
('AAA', 9,  '2021-10-01'),
('AAA', 10, '2021-10-02'),
('AAA', 8,  '2021-10-03'),
('AAA', 10, '2021-10-04'),
('BBB', 9,  '2021-10-01'),
('BBB', 11, '2021-10-02'),
('BBB', 12, '2021-10-03');

with cte1 as (
    select Stock, Price, [Date]
        , row_number() over (partition by Stock, case when Price >= 10 then 1 else 0 end order by [Date] asc) rn
        , lag(Price,1,0) over (partition by Stock order by [Date] asc) LaggedStock
    from @Table
), cte2 as (
    select Stock, Price, [Date], rn, LaggedStock
        , sum(case when Price >= 10 and LaggedStock < 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Stock) StockOver10
    from cte1
)
select Stock
    --, Price, [Date], rn, LaggedStock, StockOver10 -- debug
from cte2
where Price >= 10
and StockOver10 = 1 and rn = 1;
```

Returns:

| Stock |
| --- |
| BBB |

Note: providing DDL+DML as show above makes it much easier of people to assist.